# how do i copy one whole column from a table to another without any mutual columns or values in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have two tables:
**Movies** which contains movies names (one single column 'movie')
**Directors** which contains directors names and IDs ('director' column and 'ID' column)
i just want to copy the whole 'director' column from the second table to the first table, no where conditions available as there are no mutual columns or values between the two tables, just copy/pasta thing, both tables are equal in rows and i just want them to aggregate together
i tried many possible join/union/insert from select /update from select ways but none have worked (env is MS SQL server 2014)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you are really trying to accomplish.

Comment: What **exactly** have you tried? Why do you want to copy it, instead of leaving the structure in normalized form?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign arbitrary director's names to movies, you can use `row_number()`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select m.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
      from movies m
     )
update toupdate
    set movie = d.director
    from (select d.*, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as seqnum
          from directors d
         ) d
    where m.seqnum = d.seqnum;
```

This seems like a very curious thing to do, but it is how I interpret your question.